# Angular 10. Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

Tags: angular, build, angular10

Angular 10 application

When I try build application

```
**ng build**
```

I get next error

```
ERROR in Cannot read property 'flags' of undefined

ng --version

@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.3
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.3
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.3
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      10.0.3
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.3
@schematics/angular               10.0.3
@schematics/update                0.1000.3
rxjs                              6.6.0
typescript                        3.9.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

I try remove **node_modules**, **package.lock.json**, and **npm install**. But it is doesn't help.

Comment: search **flags** in your code. You are using in your html but not declared in .ts file.

Comment: I am not using the variable flags, looked at the whole project.

Comment: have you done npm update?

Comment: Seems like you may be missing @angular/core too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below versions:

```
@angular/cli 1.7.3
Typescript ~2.6.2
```

Comment: A wanna use angular 10